# wcf client mappath

Tags: wcf, ssrs-2008, relative-path

WCF service "ProjB" need call a function "ProcRpt(string Date)" in another proj "ProjA" in same solution. That function is located in class "Common" which deals with SSRS. And in that function need add subreport path. In Wcf Service side

```
Common cmn = new Common();
cmn.ProcRpt(t);
```

In Common ProcRpt():

```
viewerF.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewerF.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\RDLC\\rptSub.rdlc");
viewerF.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(LoadDataSource(shfDeptID, StatementDate, "f"));
```

The problem is run wcf, the subreport path point wcf folder ProjB's path not ProjA's;
How should I make it to its original path "ProjA/RDLC/rptSub.rdlc". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are about 1000 ways to skin a cat on this one.  The reason that this is happening is because that is the actual path in which your program/service/website is running in, and so using a relative path such that you have results in a sub folder of the path that the application is currently running in.

First thing you could try is to change your relative path to accomodate what you are trying to do.  Using a couple of dots (..) should allow you to go up a folder from where you are i.e.:

```
"..\\ProjA\\RDLC\\rptSub.rdlc"
```

This is probably the most "correct" way to do this.  You *could* use an absolute path, but there are security implications to doing so, in both web applications and services (as in a leet haxor might then know something about your file system, which would be bad if he/she figured out how to move around in the directories of your server.

Finally, you could (though more work, but cleaner) move your binaries into a bin folder and have relative paths to these subreports.  Having all of them (binary files) in one place on the final build is not the end of the world, and would probably alleviate some similar issues in the long run.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is I get error "The relative virtual path '../ProjA/RDLC/rptFleetwP.rdlc' is not allowed here."

Comment: Interesting... what is your hosting environment and what kind of object is ReportPath (string, Directory, etc)

Comment: asp.net 4.0; ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath should be a string; Any idea?

Comment: May sound crazy but try this: HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("../ProjA/RDLC/rptSub.rdlc"))

Comment: If you get an HttpException with that, then the user that you are running a application as does not have permission to get into the parent folder while running, which is a security feature.

Comment: Thx. But same error "The relative virtual path '../ProjA/RDLC/rptFleetwP.rdlc' is not allowed here."

Comment: Ok, that indicates that you are at the top of your virtual directory for the application path.  Once at the top, you cannot go any further without administrative rights.  Have you tried doing the absolute path to the file to see if you get any error there?

Comment: IMortalitySX, the story is on the page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165615/auto-send-monthly-email-ssrs-generate-pdf ; any suggestion?